# SSIS : I would like to pass column name inside a variable

Tags: ssis

I have used Execute SQL Task to select some columns and assign the column name in a package variable. After that I am using that package variable in the Derived Column transformation to map the column. But, when I mentioned the @[User:Variable name] in the derived column T/R, it only selects the column name as a "string value". It does not consider the the variable as the column which I am mapping.

I am passing the column name through a package variable and mentioned the variable name instead of column name in the derived column transformation. But, it just used the column name as a string value instead of mapping with the column data.

Our source tables structures vary frequently. So, we prepared one mapping table in which 2 columns are there (source table column name and Transformed column name). I need to map the source column with the source column name of the mapping table and pick the corresponding transformed column name which will be processed further. So, first through execute sql task, I fetched all the mapped source columns from mapping table and store each matched source column name into different package variables. After that in the Data Flow Task, after source adapter I used Derived Column Transformation and assign the variables instead of input column names from the source tables to new derived columns. But, here instead of picking the column values, it considers the column names which I already stored in those variables as strings.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is unclear. Could you try editing it, perhaps provide more detail so that we can recreate the issue

Comment: I am passing the column name through a package variable and mentioned the variable name instead of column name in the derived column transformation. But, it just used the column name as a string value instead of mapping with the column.

Comment: Yes, that's what I don't understand. Perhaps we try a different approach - what are hoping to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: It sounds like you are making the common mistake of thinking that there is a way to build a "generic" dataflow that can handle different data structures.   There isn't.   You might want to look into BiMLScript, which lets you dynamically create packages based on metadata.